# File Writer with String (java)

Tags: java, string, file, writer

i can't have newline in my text file with this code, what it's wrong with that?

```
try{
    oprint=new FileWriter("HighScores.txt",true);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    System.out.println("error");
}  
try{
    String stampa= "Player:  "+name+"  --- time "+ this.getDurata()+" s \n";
    oprint.write(stampa);
    oprint.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");
}
```

Comment: Well you definitely *do* have a line feed... are you saying you want one, or you don't?

Comment: Maybe you opened your file with an editor which expects to have a carriage return and linefeed (`\r\n`).

Comment: Note: Consider to use Automatic Resource Management if you're using Java SE 7.

Comment: What platform are you developing for? Try using `%n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

and then:

```
oprint.write("Player:  " + "x" + "  --- time " + "durata" + " s " + newline);
```

This is better as different OS's have different ways of writing new lines. Linux uses "\n", Mac uses "\r", and Windows uses "\r\n" for newline.

Comment: There is actually a [`newLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()) method in `Writer`, but the sensible approach is to utilise a `PrintWriter` or a `PrintStream`. Then you'll have `println` to take care of this.

Comment: f*** i'm using the basic txt editor of windows. if i use wordpad newlines appear. thx to everybody

Comment: Just a side-note but if he produces a file on a different platform than where he tries to read it, then it's a better ide to explicit write out the correct line separator, not the system preferred.

Comment: @ftom2 Windows uses `\r\n`, not Linux

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your editor or viewer does not expect to have a carriage return (CR) at the end of the lines?

If so try with the following:

```
String stampa = "Player:  "+name+"  --- time "+ this.getDurata()+" s \r\n";
```

Or you could use the [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String stampa = String.format("Player: %s  --- time %d s %n", name, this.getDurata());
```

From the [format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

> `'n'`  line separator  The result is the platform-specific line
>   separator

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe to wrap `FileWriter` in `PrintWriter` and use its `println()` method.

```
PrintWriter oprint;
try{
    oprint=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("HighScores.txt",true));
    String stampa= "Player:  "+name+"  --- time "+ this.getDurata()+" s";
    oprint.println(stampa);//<- print with new line sign
    oprint.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("error");
}
```